# Redirect to basic page after login or registration Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

is it possible to redirect user to / after login? When i do this, there is, that you are not authenticated, but login or registration button doesn't work, because you are authenticated. When I redirect to /home, it works good. It says that you are authenticated and everything work. It's still the same file home.blade.php, just url is different... (sudoman281.cz, sudoman281.cz/home). Thank you.

```
    class Authenticate
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                return redirect()->guest('login');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/');
        }


        return $next($request);

    }
}


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});

Route::get('login', function () {
    return view('auth.login');
});

Route::get('/register', function () {
    return view('auth.register');
});
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This route group applies the "web" middleware group to every route
| it contains. The "web" middleware group is defined in your HTTP
| kernel and includes session state, CSRF protection, and more.
|
*/

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    //
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();

    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

Comment: You already have protected $redirectTo = '/'; which redirect users to '/' so not sure what your question is.

Comment: Try to clear your route caches: php artisan route:clear

If it keeps failing post us your routes please (php artisan route:list). It may be cache or a typo.

Comment: Why do you have two routes Route::get('/')? The second one that leads to HomeController will not work.

Comment: The problem is not in redirecting to / page, but when it redirect user to this page, it shows, that user is not authenticated. But if url is with home and redirect_to is set to /home it works

Answer (score 0):

I already know, how to fix this problem:
Only thing you have to do is add

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::auth();

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('home');
    });
});
```

to your routes.php.